# Python logger is not always logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a problem with my logging in my python script. I run the same script multiple times (to have several simulations) using `Pool` for increased performance. In my script I'm using a logger with MemoryHandler, defined as below:

```
capacity=5000000000
filehandler_name = SOME_NAME
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

filehandler = logging.FileHandler(filehandler_name)
memoryhandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(
                capacity=capacity,
                flushLevel=logging.ERROR,
                target=filehandler
                )

logger.addHandler(memoryhandler)
```

and I log information using `logger.info(...)`. However, I noticed that the logging is not always working. When I check different log files (I have one log sile per simulation), some log files contain data, the others are empty. There is not particular pattern in which are empty and which are not, usually it happens at random. I tried many things but it seems like I'm missing something. Does anyone has any suggestion on why Python logger might not be always working corretly?

Comment: How are you opening and writing to the files? Without a [mcve] this isn't really well-formed.

Comment: The opening and writing into the file is handled by the Memory Handler and File Handler, i don't open or write explicitely into the file. The only command which I call is logger.info("Log some information")

Answer (score 0):

Without a code snippet I would guess it is caused by the multiprocessing, you mention:

> using Pool for increased performance..

You can check the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) on how to use logging module while multiprocessing.